# Is there a default transaction for the SaveChanges method?

Tags: entity-framework, transactions

If I made multiple operations with the same Entity Framework `DbContext` (add and update)
with one call to `SaveChanges`, are those changes will be done as a Transaction or not?

```
using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Table1.Add(entity1);
    context.Table2.Add(entity2);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

or is there a chance to execute just one of them without executing the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's wrapped in a transaction:

> In all versions of Entity Framework, whenever you execute
>   SaveChanges() to insert, update or delete on the database the
>   framework will wrap that operation in a transaction. This transaction
>   lasts only long enough to execute the operation and then completes.
>   When you execute another such operation a new transaction is started.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/transactions

You can't do any partial save, otherwise, your DbContext could get into inconsistent state. You can only call `SaveChanges` multiple times after each change operation.